# Google query for a mass of related websites

Tags: google-custom-search, google-query-language

Is there a way to load a bunch of urls like a hundred of them and query in google to find other related to those.

To be more specific the command `as_rq=www.example.com` in google query searches sites that are related to this url, what if I want to search for a vast amount of urls is there an option or I'll have to traverse all the urls one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap it is possible via Google CSE(custom search engine) API where on the required parameter `q=exampleQuery` you insert `q=as_rq=www.example.com`and by using annotations you can parametrize your search results.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do multiple url queries. I've tried to do this myself before with no luck after searching multiple online forumns

Comment: I have seen just seen the https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api ,where on the step 2 if I am correct you can insert many webpages as annotations to exclude from your custom search, nonetheless I think the whole procedure needs some cash.